# Cognito Visitor Bind to Future User Pool Identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I'm trying to design a flow that would have two kinds of users,
let's call them logged in users and visitors.
The idea is that logged in users can create data base entries and when they're ready
they can send an email invite to visitors that would then be able to view the items assigned to them and only if the visitors choose to they could create an account and then edit the resource.

My question is - is there's a cognito flow that allows this or do I need to manage visitors myself somehow?

Thanks!

to be clear I mean that the visitors would get a link to the site with some temporary token not an actual copy of the document so they would actually be accessing live data

Comment: i've allowed myself to ask a more specific question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78126714/cognito-user-invite

Answer (score 0):

It's allow the cognito, you define the login user types.

Comment: thanks, could you please elaborate or send a link to docs?