# Cognito User Invite

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I'm creating an app where authenticated users can send invites to potential users who would not go through authentication,
the idea is to give them some sort of access token so they can view a resource and that the invite sending their phone or email the app would have already created some sort of temporary identity that would later be their user pool id in case they choose to sign up.

can anyone explain how to go about this, would it be the same user pool, I understand there's some way to create different types of users etc.

Thanks